# Display environment differently for one use vs. two

Tags: environments

My issue can be boiled down to this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{mygroup}{
  \vspace{.15in}

  \textbf{\large MyGroup Heading}
}{
}

\newenvironment{mylist}[1]{
  \newcommand{\myitem}[1]{
    \item ##1:%
  }

  \vspace{.12in}

  \emph{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont#1}
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
}{
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{mygroup}
    \begin{mylist}{subheading 1}
      \myitem{item 1} item 1 content
      \myitem{item 2} item 2 content
    \end{mylist}
    \begin{mylist}{subheading 2}
      \myitem{another item} content
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mygroup}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Currently, I display subheadings no matter how many `mylist`s there are inside a `mygroup`.  How do I make it so that subheadings only display if there are two or more `mylist`s in a `mygroup`, and if there is only one, its subheading is not displayed?

Comment: I'm confused by your question; if there are two `mylist`s, subheadings would not be omitted.

Comment: apologies.  i misread your last paragraph.  deleting comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses my `cntperchap` package which stores total counters per chapter level, but this could be set to another counter as well. Here, the `mygroup` is set as tracklevel.

The `\GetStoredCounterValue{mylist}` gets the value from a previous run and stores it to `cps@@tempstoragecounter` counter, which can then be queried with `\ifnumgreater` (which is from `etoolbox`, but this package is loaded by `cntperchap` already.

(Side note: I have to change the documentation and the `\GetStoredCounterValue` approach in the next release -- it's not convenient so far.)

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{mygroup}
\usepackage[tracklevel=mygroup]{cntperchap}

\newcounter{mylist} % track the lists

\RegisterCounters{mylist} % prepare for tracking

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{mygroup}{%
  \vspace{.15in}
  \textbf{\large MyGroup Heading}
}{
}

\makeatother

\newenvironment{mylist}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mylist}%
  \GetStoredCounterValue{mylist}%
  \newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
    \item ##1:%
  }

  \vspace{.12in}

  \ifnumgreater{\value{cps@@tempcounterstorage}}{1}{%
    \emph{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont#1}
  }{}%

  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
  }{%
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{mygroup}
    \begin{mylist}{subheading 1}
      \myitem{item 1} item 1 content
      \myitem{item 2} item 2 content
    \end{mylist}
    \begin{mylist}{subheading 2}
      \myitem{another item} content
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mygroup}

  \begin{mygroup}
   \begin{mylist}{subheading 1 which isn't displayed}
     \myitem{item 1} Just one list, part 1
     \myitem{item 2} Just one list, part 2
   \end{mylist}
 \end{mygroup}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, I have been struggling to get this installed, but I cannot get it to work, unfortunately.  I tried digging through the code, and I am having trouble following it... my TeX just isn't good enough, yet.  Would you be willing to add another answer that boils down your solution to the most basic thing that would work without installing `cntperchap`?

Comment: @Nate: You can just put `cntperchap.sty` in your working directory. It was some hard work to make `cntperchap` work in general, but the effort for a 'small' problem like yours is effectively the same, so it would mean reinventing the wheel again. I can try, but can't promise to succeed.

Comment: I believe you... sadly, I think I may be working with an older version that doesn't support `cntperchap`.  I tried following your suggestion to copy it into my working directory, but it gave me errors.  If this is so complicated, I may just have to give up.

Comment: @Nate: Apparently, you've got an older TeX distribution then. I will try another approach, but this might take some time

Comment: Actually, I came up with another approach.  Thanks for all your help!  I believe this is a better answer so I will to accept yours, even though I couldn't use it myself.

Answer (score 1):

After meditating on Christian's answer and doing a bit more googling, I came up with a solution that uses the `totcount` package instead:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newcounter{mygroupcount}

\newenvironment{mygroup}{
  \stepcounter{mygroupcount}
  \edef\mycount{mycount\alph{mygroupcount}}
  \expandafter\newtotcounter\expandafter{\mycount}
  \vspace{.15in}

  \textbf{\large MyGroup Heading}
}{
}

\newenvironment{mylist}[1]{
  \stepcounter{\mycount}
  \newcommand{\myitem}[1]{
    \item ##1:%
  }

  \vspace{.12in}

  \ifnum 1<\totvalue{\mycount}
    \emph{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont#1}
  \fi
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
}{
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{mygroup}
    \begin{mylist}{subheading 1}
      \myitem{item 1} item 1 content
      \myitem{item 2} item 2 content
    \end{mylist}
    \begin{mylist}{subheading 2}
      \myitem{another item} content
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mygroup}
  \begin{mygroup}
    \begin{mylist}{subheading 1 - not shown}
      \myitem{item 1} item 1 content
      \myitem{item 2} item 2 content
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mygroup}
\end{document}
```

As Christian's solution is a bit simpler, I would prefer to use that, but for an older TeX distribution, this works.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Basically you are doing something similar what I've done, but `\newtotcounter` each time `mygroup` is used, isn't the best idea. It will work, as long as there no severe counter registers manipulations occur (I assume, that you won't do this anyway)  (+1)